# Cumulative Geometric Brownian Motion

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, mathematical-physics, mathematical-modeling

If I accumulate the realisations of a Geometric Brownian Motion, with drift=$\mu$, volatility=$\sigma$ and initial value $x_0$, what will the resulting process be? Some mathematical justifications and/or references will be appreciated.

By the "accumulated" process we mean the sum $X_T = \int_0^T S_t dt$.

Comment: A typical justification is that when in mathematical finance a stock price or a foreign exchange rate is modelled as a geometric Brownian motion (Black-Scholes model) then the time average of that will be the underlying of an [*Asian option*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asian_option).

Comment: What is meant by "accumulate"? Do you mean the process $X_T = \int_0^T S_t dt $ where $S$ is a Geometric Brownian Motion or do you mean the sum of independent (or perhaps dependent in some way) realisations of GBM, .i.e $X_t = \sum_k S_t^k$, or something else?

Comment: I mean $X_T = \int_0^T S_t dt$, where $S$ is a Geometric Brownian Motion yes, accumulating the realisations of the same GBM process. The second could also be interesting perhaps, but I am looking for the former.